# How to filter records in CoreData using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have amount attribute in coredata model with string datatype. I need to find records by comparing amount. I have tried NSPredicate with following but nothing is coming and result is always empty.

```
NSDecimal result;
NSScanner *theScanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:@"10.00"];
[theScanner scanDecimal:&result];
[theScanner release];



 [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"amount > %@",[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:result]]];
 NSError* error = nil;
 NSArray* records = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 NSLog(@"%@",records);
```

Please remember that i am storing amount value in string data type in coredata. following are some examples of what i am storting into data.

```
Examples: -12.00, +30.00 etc.
```

I know storing decimal values in string type is not good, but i didn't find a good way to store amount with negative or positive mark within coredata attribute. let me if there is any good way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Decimal` data type for amounts (corresponds with `NSDecimalNumber` class in Objective-C).

Comment: Thanks, I did but now the problem is i am unable to compare amount value like following. amount < 0 of model

Comment: I tried the following ([amount doubleValue] <= 0) and it worked.
As i understood NSDecimalNumber is a structure and we can't compate it directly as i did before.

Thanks

Comment: `NSDecimalNumber` is a subclass of NSNumber.